PNP Modern Search v4 - Search list not returning list column data
I  am trying to configure PNP Modern Search web parts to apply search and filter options against a specific list but I can't get the options to populate the Selected Properties dropdown with the list fields.
I can manually edit the values but the content is coming through as null values in debug view even though the values are present in list when viewed:

Does anyone have any ideas if I've missed something in configuration or anything is incorrect?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Have redacted some data in screenshot related to tenant etc.

Please check if you list related crawl properties are created in crawl properties? You can verify that at https:///_layouts/15/listcrawledproperties.aspx?level=site
